# Spark left outer join memory issue

Tags: apache-spark, join, memory

I have a Spark job which gives me a *Java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space* (or some GC overhead).

It appears in a task whithin a stage where the statics for complete tasks show the 75 percentile memory and disk spill are 0 but for maximum they are respectively 1732.5 MB and 145.5 MB.

I am pretty sure I have a key which represents more than 70% of all lines during a leftOuterJoin.

Is there a way to spread values associates to this key on multiple partition when doing this join?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depending on the size of your data you could try a broadcast join (essentially a map join)

http://henning.kropponline.de/2016/12/11/broadcast-join-with-spark/